# Twig form does not appear

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I made a twig form to search on my missions objects , I have the mission page where are referenced all of the missions, and the search form does not appear upside.

the form supposed to be on the second greyzone starting from top.

mission repository

```
<?php

namespace App\Repository;

use App\Entity\Mission;
use App\Entity\MissionSearch;
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ServiceEntityRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;
use Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder;


/**
 * @method Mission|null find($id, $lockMode = null, $lockVersion = null)
 * @method Mission|null findOneBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null)
 * @method Mission[]    findAll()
 * @method Mission[]    findBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null, $limit = null, $offset = null)
 */
class MissionRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $registry)
    {
        parent::__construct($registry, Mission::class);
    }

    /**
     * @return Query
     */
    public function findAllVisibleQuery(MissionSearch $search): Query
    {
        $query = $this->findVisibleQuery();

        if ($search->getMaxGain()) {
            $query = $query
                ->andWhere('m.gain <= :maxgain')
                ->setParameter('maxgain', $search->getMaxGain());
        }

        if ($search->getDeltaVille()) {
            $query = $query
                ->andWhere('m.ville = :deltaville')
                ->setParameter('deltaville', $search->getDeltaVille());
        }



        return $query->getQuery();
    }


    /**
     * @return Mission[]
     */
    public function findLatest(): array
    {
        return $this->findVisibleQuery()
            ->setMaxResults(900)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
    }

    private function findVisibleQuery(): QueryBuilder
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('m')
            ->where('m.Accepted = false');
    }

    // /**
    //  * @return Mission[] Returns an array of Mission objects
    //  */
    /*
    public function findByExampleField($value)
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('m')
            ->andWhere('m.exampleField = :val')
            ->setParameter('val', $value)
            ->orderBy('m.id', 'ASC')
            ->setMaxResults(10)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult()
        ;
    }
    */

    /*
    public function findOneBySomeField($value): ?Mission
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('m')
            ->andWhere('m.exampleField = :val')
            ->setParameter('val', $value)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getOneOrNullResult()
        ;
    }
    */
}
```

twig template

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title 'Missions' %}

{% block body %}
    <div class="jumbotron text-center">
        <h1>Trouvez une mission qui vous correspond</h1>
        <p>My super est encore en developpement , vous pouvez apporter vos idées via le formulaire de contact</p>
    </div>

    <div class="jumbotron text-center">
        <div class="container">
            {% if form is defined %}

            {{ form_start(form) }}
            <div class="form-row align-items-end">
                <div class="col">
                    {{ form_row(form.maxGain) }}
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    {{ form_row(form.deltaVille) }}
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary">Rechercher</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            {{ form_end(form) }}
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="container">
        <h2>Les dernieres missions</h2>
        <div class="row flex">

            {% for mission in missions %}
                <div class="col-3">
                    <div class="card mb-4">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title">
                                <a href="{{ path('mission.show', {id: mission.id, slug: mission.slug}) }}">{{ mission.titre }}</a>
                            </h5>
                            <p class="card-text">{{ mission.adresse }} {{ mission.ville }}</p>
                            <div class="text-primary" style="font-weight: bold;font-size: 2rem;">{{ mission.gain }} €</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>


            {% endfor %}



        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

pagecontroller (missioncontroller)

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Repository\MissionRepository;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use App\Entity\Mission;


class LesmissionsController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/lesmissions", name="lesmissions")
     * @param MissionRepository $repository
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index(MissionRepository $repository): Response
    {
        $missions = $repository->findLatest();
        return $this->render('lesmissions/index.html.twig', [
            'missions' => $missions
        ]);
    }

}[![form supposed to be on the second greyzone starting from top][1]][1]
```

thanx by advance

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? It's not common that something is simply "not rendered"

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the form and put it as parameter inside render()

```
public function index(MissionRepository $repository, FormFactoryInterface $formfactory): Response
{
    $missions = $repository->findLatest();

    $form = $formFactory->create(YourCustomFormType::class,);

    return $this->render('lesmissions/index.html.twig', [
        'missions' => $missions,
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ]);
}
```

Your Form looks similar to this I guess:

```
class YourCustomFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('maxGain', TextType::class)
            ->add('deltaVille', TextType::class);
    }
}
```